# Which assets should I provide for full width display, and how to name them?

Tags: ios, assets, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Here is the basic example of what I'd like to show in my app.

- `bg` is a background image that must fit the entire screen
- `left` is an image that fits the left half of the screen in width ; its width/height ratio is square
- `right` is an image that fits the right half of the screen in width ; its width/height ratio is square

[image: Sample application for asset naming example]

Before iPhone 6, I would have provided the following :

```
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| Asset name     | Width (px) | Height (px) | Devices            |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| bg.png         |        320 |         480 | iPhone 3GS         |
| bg@2x.png      |        640 |         960 | iPhone 4           |
| bg-568h@2x.png |        640 |        1136 | iPhone 5           |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| left.png       |        160 |         160 | iPhone 3GS         |
| left@2x.png    |        320 |         320 | iPhone 4, iPhone 5 |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| right.png      |        160 |         160 | iPhone 3GS         |
| right@2x.png   |        320 |         320 | iPhone 4, iPhone 5 |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

With the new iPhone 6 / 6 plus width, what assets should I provide, and how should I name them ? How do we even define a "half width" for an iPhone 6 (or 6 plus zoom mode), given that the number of points is odd ?

Here is a suggestion, but I'm not sure it really fits common practice :

```
+-------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| Asset name        | Width (px) | Height (px) | Devices                                |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| bg.png            |        320 |         480 | iPhone 3GS                             |
| bg@2x.png         |        640 |         960 | iPhone 4                               |
| bg-568h@2x.png    |        640 |        1136 | iPhone 5, iPhone 6 zoom mode           |
| bg-667h@2x.png    |        750 |        1334 | iPhone 6                               |
| bg-667h@3x.png    |       1125 |        2001 | iPhone 6 plus zoom mode                |
| bg@3x.png         |       1242 |        2208 | iPhone 6 plus                          |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| left.png          |        160 |         160 | iPhone 3GS                             |
| left@2x.png       |        320 |         320 | iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 zoom mode |
| left-375w@2x.png  |        375 |         375 | iPhone 6                               |
| left-375w@3x.png  |        562 |         563 | iPhone 6 plus zoom mode                |
| left@3x.png       |        621 |         621 | iPhone 6 plus                          |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| right.png         |        160 |         160 | iPhone 3GS                             |
| right@2x.png      |        320 |         320 | iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 zoom mode |
| right-375w@2x.png |        375 |         375 | iPhone 6                               |
| right-375w@3x.png |        563 |         563 | iPhone 6 plus zoom mode                |
| right@3x.png      |        621 |         621 | iPhone 6 plus                          |
+-------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Note that 375px at a @2x scale, and 562 or 563 px at a @3x scale aren't even valid measurements in points. The best approach for keeping integer values would be 374/376 @2x and 561/564px @3x...